# Do interviews work?

Tags: interviewing

The ideal answer would contain:

- A concise summary of what the existing research says about the effectiveness of job interviews; and
- Concrete recommendations on what employers should or shouldn't do.

Comment: flagging for close on the grounds of too broad.

Comment: Also flagged. Answering this basically calls for hundreds of studies and dozens of papers and books

Comment: My last  interview got me a job, so I would say that it worked.

Answer (score 2):

> Do interviews work?

Yes they do, without them you don't know anything about a candidate except what is in their CV.